# Opting out XNA based Windows Phone 8 game from the Windows Phone 7 Store

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, 3d, xna

We have a little problem with our 3D game being displayed in the WP7 Store as well. Our game was developed exclusively on Windows Phone 8 devices, but since it’s based on XNA, WP7 users can see and download the game as well. We handled the situation by letting the people know - after they launch the app - that it isn’t supported for their OS.

That is a temporary fix, because people get mad being able to download a game, but not being able to play it. So we might get bad reviews because of that. We’ve tried several things, like porting our app into Monogame to make it WP8 exclusive, but that didn’t work out, since Monogame itself is in beta phase and therefore pretty buggy.

Do you know any solution to opt out the game from the WP7 store or make it hidden there by adding any specific code? People are likely to give us a 1-star review because of something like that and obviously we do not want that.

Is there any way, besides Monogame, for us to fix this issue?

Kind regards.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the WMAppManifest.xml with `AppPlattformVersion="8.0"`?